# How to remove getError message from EditText in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-textinputlayout

I had used **setError** method for an **EditText** when the user keeps that field blank. But, when the user again tries to write down the password then I want that error red color icon and message to get removed. I tried **setError(null)** as written in the code but still it is not working.

```
 String val = password.getEditText().getText().toString();

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            password.setError("Please enter password");
            return false;
        } else {
            password.setError(null);
            password.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: I do not see `setError()` or `setErrorEnabled()` in [the JavaDocs for `EditText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText). And I am fairly certain that `EditText` does not have a `getEditText()` method.  What is `password`?

Comment: I am using TextInputLayout and not a not a normal EditText

Comment: `setError()` is there in `TextView` and `EditText` extend  `TextView`.
`password` must be TextInputLayout because there both `setError()` and `setErrorEnabled()` are available

Comment: sorry comment didn't loaded for me, thanks Rohan for clarification of password type

Answer (score 2):

You can use TextWatcher to monitor the changes in EditText value. Refer below code:

```
 password.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           if (s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                password.setError("Please enter password");
                return false;
            } else {
                password.setError(null);
                password.setErrorEnabled(false);
                return true;
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi @AlphaOne  this **addTextChangedListener** is available only in case of EditText and not for TextInputLayout. Can you please help me out that which one to use for this

Comment: @Rohanverma you can try this: `view.getEditText().addTextChangedListener()` where `view` is the @id for your TextLayoutInput, which in your case I think is **password**. This should work.

Comment: @Rohanverma you can use password.getEditText() as suggested by Yash. Or you can give an Id to your EditText and use that here.

Comment: Hi @YashJoshi and AlphaOne, thanks man it had worked perfectly now